# regex to match an exam result

Tags: python, regex

here is the key structure

```
first part + '-' + second part
```

first part is from a list of indicators

```
'BIL|UBG|LEU|ERY|pH|KET|SG|PRO|NIT|GLU'
```

second part is an int + '+/-' or a 'pos/neg'
here is bottom line of what I got

```
(BIL|UBG|LEU|ERY|pH|KET|SG|PRO|NIT)-[0-9][+,-]
```

like these

```
NIT-3+
GLU-pos
pH-neg
```

didn't get the second part right,..

Comment: Looks like you need to add `pos|neg` to your regex? Or if not that, could you explain a bit more - I'm not 100% sure what your question/problem is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
(BIL|UBG|LEU|ERY|pH|KET|SG|PRO|NIT|GLU)-((pos|neg)|[0-9][+,-])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vY5gN5/1)